# Combining CSS and custom CSS properties inline on a react component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I need to pass custom CSS properties inline to a React component (Google Model Viewer in this instance),combined with more run-of-the-mill styles (background width, height etc.).  There's quite a lot of questions on using custom properties inline with react, but I couldn't see one for specifically combing the properties with other styles.

I have the styles here, with the commented out style being an example of the custom property.

```
const styles = {
      width: "100%",
      height: "100%",
      background: this.props.background,
     // "--progress-bar-height": this.props.progressBarHeight
 };
```

The const gets passed into rendering the component:

```
return (
      <model-viewer
        style={styles}
      </model-viewer>
```

How do I combine the usual inline styles with the custom properties to add inline?

I tried adding it as a variable (as seen elsewhere on SO):

```
const progressBarHeight={ "--progress-bar-height": this.props.progressBarHeight };
```

But wasn't sure how to combine that with the `{styles}` . I tried longhand declaring each style and adding the variable to the list, but that didnt work either:

```
 style={{ background: styles.background, width: styles.width, height: styles.height, progressBarHeight }}
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use object spreading for this

```
style={{...styles, ...progressBarHeight }} // progressBarHeight = { "--customrvar" : '1px'}
```

Here's a working [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-cray-vikxe?file=/src/index.js)

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't a simple object map work?
Here is a sample code -

```
const styles = {
      width: "100%",
      height: "100%",
      background: "this.props.background",
      //"--progress-bar-height": "black"
 };
 
 const props = {
      "--progress-bar-height": "white"
 }
 
 for(let i in props)
 {
    styles[i] = props[i];   
 }
 
 for(let i in styles)
 {
    console.log(styles[i]);   
 }
```

And then the resulting combined style goes into props of your component.